# Does anyone have experience with how TCPCopy effects the performance of network transactions?

Tags: process, monitor, antivirus

When looking at Process monitor from Microsoft Technet, I see the TCP send Receive and Copy.
I notice that the Copy appears to be a replication of a transmission, but dont understand why it happens sometimes and not others.

[Screen shot of TCPCopy issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hr9E4.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe "TCPCopy" event indicates that the received TCP packet is cloned/mirrored by another program (typically antivirus). From your screenshot, it looks like there's an antivirus scanning Outlook (POP/SMTP/IMAP) and Firefox (HTTP/S) packets. Can you try disabling mail and web traffic scanning (or realtime scanning) in your antivirus, and check if you still notice TCPCopy events in Process Monitor?

Comment: I still see TCPCopy when removing antivirus from my system .  What else could be causing this to happen? Could it be Windows Firewall? How can i tell what would be doing this?